# sudoers - Google Compute Engine - no access to root

Tags: root, google-compute-engine, sudoers

I have a Google Compute Engine VM instance with a Asterisk Server running on it. I get this message when I try to run `sudo`:

```
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 21
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Is there a password for root so I can try to change it there? Any suggestions on this?

Comment: you need to get from your server admin

Comment: that´s me ;) - Do you know of Google Cloud Engine provide to reset the Root from console.developers.google.com?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you have manually edited the `/etc/sudoers` file so while you would normally have `sudo` access, due to the parse error, you won't be able to do this directly.

Here's how to fix this situation.

**1. Save the current boot disk**

- go to to the instance view in Developers Console
- find your VM instance and click on its name; you should now be looking at a URL such as
  `https://console.cloud.google.com/project/[PROJECT]/compute/instancesDetail/zones/[ZONE]/instances/[VM-NAME]`
- [stop the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance)
- [detach the boot disk from the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk)

**2. Fix the `/etc/sudoers` on the boot disk**

- create a new VM instance with its own boot disk; you should have `sudo` access here
- [attach](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) the disk saved above as a separate persistent disk
- mount the disk you just attached
- fix the `/etc/sudoers` file on the disk
- unmount the second disk
- detach the second disk from the VM
- delete the new VM instance (let it delete its boot disk, you won't need it)

**3. Restore the original VM instance**

- re-attach the boot disk to the original VM
- restart the original VM with its original boot disk, with fixed config

**How to avoid this in the future**

Always use the command [`visudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/visudo.man.html) rather just any text editor directly to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file which will validate the contents of the file prior to saving it.

Comment: Hey Great! I was about to start from the beginning. You saved my Day!

Comment: You also can probably do `EDITOR=nano visudo` or have a root session in screen for emergency fix.

Comment: 2. Fix the /etc/sudoers on the boot disk: worked perfectly for me. Thanks for the solution

Comment: I followed these steps and it when I detatched the disk from my server it deleted everything. Great.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this issue as well and had the same issue Nakilon was reporting when trying the gcloud workaround.

What we ended up doing was configure a startup script that removed the broken sudoers file.

So in your `metadata` put something like:

```
#/bin/sh

rm "/etc/sudoers.d/broken-config-file"
echo "ok" > /tmp/ok.log
```

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

Comment: All the other answers were not working except this perfect solution, thanks a lot and it saved my day

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked but I also had to run `usermod -aG sudo username`. Anyway, that's the way to recover root access :)

Answer (score 1):

As you probably figured out this requires the /etc/sudoers file to be fixed. As nobody has root access to the instance, you will not be able to do this from inside the instance.

The best way to solve this is to [edit the disk from another instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#mount_your_disk_on_a_temporary_instance). The basic steps to do this are:

1. Take a snapshot of your disk as a backup (!)
2. Shutdown your instance, taking care not to delete the boot disk.
3. Start a new "debugger" instance from one of the stock GCE images.
4. [Attach the old boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#attachdiskrunninginstance) to the new instance.
5. In the debugger instance, mount the disk.
6. In the debugger instance, fix the sudoers file on the mounted disk.
7. In the debugger instance, unmount the disk
8. Shutdown the debugger instance.
9. Create a new instance with the same specs as your original instance using the fixed disk as the boot disk.

The new disk will then have the fixed sudoers file.

Answer (score 1):

Since i bumped into this issue too, if you have another instance or any place where you can run with gcloud privileges, you can run:

```
gcloud compute --project "<project id>" ssh --zone "europe-west1-b" "<servername>"
```

I ran this on a server which had gcloud as root, so you login to the other box as root too! Then fix your issue. (if you don't have a box, just spin a micro up with the correct gcloud privileges) saves the hassle of disk stuff etc.

Comment: `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].`

Comment: this works a lot better than deleting/recreating the instance!  Thanks!

Comment: Oh man!. Thanks for the great hack for this issue in Gcp.. This really solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in above comments, I am getting the same error like below in gcp VM.

```
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 21
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

To solve this

I have ssh to another vm and become root then I ran gcloud ssh command to our main vm (where you are getting the sudo error.)

```
gcloud compute --project "<project id>" ssh --zone "europe-west1-b "<servername>"
```

And BOOM!, now are login as root in the VM.

Now you can access/change the `/etc/sudoers` file accordingly.

I found this hack better than recreating vm/disks.
Hope this helps to someone!

Comment: You are my hero. Just a tip: it's possible to do it directly from the Cloud Shell machine, just remember to do "sudo su" in the Cloud Shell before running the gcloud command.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to connect to a VM as root from your developers console Google Cloud Shell. Make sure the VM is running, start the shell and use this command:

```
gcloud compute ssh root@<instance-name> --zone <zone> [--project <project-id>]
```

where `instance-name` is found in the Compute Engine VM Instances screen. `project-id` is optional but required if you are connecting to an instance in a different project from the project where you started the shell.

You can then fix this and other issues that may prevent you from using `sudo`.

Comment: `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].`

Answer (score 0):

I got a Permission denied error when trying to ssh to the problem instance via gcloud. Using a startup script as mentioned above by @Jorick works. Instructions for it are [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux#passing-directly). You will have to stop and restart the VM instance for the startup script to get executed. I modified the script slightly:

```
rm -f /etc/sudoers.d/google_sudoers >& /tmp/startup.log
```

After the restart, launch an SSH session from the cloud console and check that you are able to view the file contents (with `sudo more /etc/sudoers.d/google_sudoers` for example). If that works your problem has been solved.